# BUKKIT - MINECRAFT Setting gamemode issue

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I started developing plugin for my server. I made main class and pleh commands but all stopped when I started with `gamemode` command. I mean it works with no errors but gives no output. It could be a simple mistake but I can't find it.

Here is my code:

```
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.inventory.InventoryClickEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.Inventory;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Gamemode implements CommandExecutor {

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) {

        if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Haha nice try not happening today.");
            return true;
        }
        Player p = (Player) sender;
        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("gm")) {
            if ((!p.hasPermission("sutils.*")) &&
                    (!p.hasPermission("sutils.gamemode"))) {
                p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Sorry no permission.");
                return true;
            }
            if (args.equals("0")) {
                p.setGameMode(GameMode.SURVIVAL);
                p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Gamemode set to Survival");
            }

            if (args.equals("1")) {
                p.setGameMode(GameMode.CREATIVE);
                p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Gamemode set to Creative");
            }

            if (args.equals("2")) {
                p.setGameMode(GameMode.ADVENTURE);
                p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Gamemode set to Adventure");
            }

            if (args.equals("3")) {
                p.setGameMode(GameMode.SPECTATOR);
                p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Gamemode set to Spectator");
            }
            return true;

        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Actually, the only thing that happens is when I type command in console it sends me my not a player msg but as player nope does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The situation you have here is the following:
'args' is not a single string, but an array of strings.
That being said, you cannot check if an array of strings is equal to a string.

So what you must do is:

- Check if args isn't null
- Check if args[0].equals("0") or if args[1].equals("1")...

With args[0], we try to access the argument at position 0 of the command. Something like this:

/gm 1

- GM is the commandlabel of your command
- 1 is argument 0 of your command

For that, we can do the following:

```
if (args == null) {
    p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You must use an arg!");
    return false;
}

if (args[0].equals("0") {
    p.setGameMode(GameMode.SURVIVAL);
    p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Gamemode set to survival");
    return true;
} else if (args[0].equals("1") {
    //Setgamemode to creative
    //......
}
```

That should do the trick!

Comment: You had a typo in there, i fixed it tho. I totally agree with your post, but I want to add, that i´d use switch instead of if in this case. Depending on your java version you need to convert args[0] to integer. The reason why is just because its cleaner imo